# Combined elasticY over multiple charts

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I would like to set the axis of a barchart by a function, but outside of the `elasticY()` syntax. The use case here is that I have two bar charts in the same dimension/group, like so:

```
chart1
.dimension(dim).group(gr)
.valueAccessor(d => d.value.one)
.elasticY()
```

and

```
chart1
.dimension(dim).group(gr)
.valueAccessor(d => d.value.two)
.elasticY()
```

These work, but elasticY() sets the domains individually, meaning the axes of the two charts don't align. I can set `.y(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,100]))` But that makes the chart's static. What I'd prefer to do is something like:

```
.valueAccessor(function(d) {
result = func(d)// function to return the max of value.one and value.two
chart1.y().domain([0, result])
return d.value.one;
}
```

But this doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Which chart are you using? Do you have `elasticY(true)` set? Elastic will calculate the domain each time and it sounds like you don't want that. Your first code should work if elastic is disabled. The chart will set the scale to the axis, so you shouldn't do the second code.

Comment: Ah! yes, I did have elasticY set. I'll try that, thank you! Do you know if there's a way to set the domain dynamically (i.e. in response to new filters)?

Comment: That's what elasticY is supposed to do? I'm confused, do you want to set it manually or have it automatic?

Comment: Sorry, this is outside the scope of the original question. But I have three barcharts that I want to force on the same axis. elasticY sets each axis based on the values of the individual chart. Setting them to a static domain is better, but setting them to the max domain of all observations would be best. Your original question answers the thread, though. I'll check it off if you duplicate below.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect the new, more interesting question. I think the original question is well enough covered and there is no need to answer it.

Comment: Fair enough. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.elasticY(true)` causes the chart to compute the minimum and maximum values each time the chart is drawn, and apply them to the domain of the Y scale.

If you want a more complex behavior, you can set `elasticY(false)` and add `preRender` and `preRedraw` [handlers](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#on) that do set the domain the way you want.

Here is a function that

- takes a list of charts
- creates a `preRender`/`preRedraw` handler which

  - computes the max of all values across all charts, by concatenating `.group().all()` of all the charts and applying [d3.max()](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/v1.2.4/README.md#max)
  - and applies the domain `[0, maxY]` to the chart
  - calls `.rescale()` to tell the chart the scale has changed:

The handler:

```
const common_elasticY = charts => chart => {
    const maxY = d3.max(Array.prototype.concat.apply([],
        charts.map(c => c.group().all())), kv => kv.value);
    chart.y().domain([0, maxY]);
    chart.rescale();
};
```

Instantiate the handler on the list of charts:

```
const preHandler = common_elasticY([yearBarChart, spendBarChart]);
```

Install the handler for the `preRender` and `preRedraw` events for each chart:

```
yearBarChart.on('preRender', preHandler)
  .on('preRedraw', preHandler);
spendBarChart.on('preRender', preHandler)
  .on('preRedraw', preHandler);
```

[image: two bar charts with combined elasticY]

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/2Lncfk1r/53/).